# Any tools to document Java POJO transformer code?

Tags: java, hibernate, transformation, documentation-generation, auto-generate

I've inherited a project which essentially maps large documents from one structure to another. The source and target documents are POJOs, and there are a number of transformer classes that map the source POJO to the target by using the getters/setters of each field.

For example, say we have:

```
public void transform(SourceDocument source, TargetDocument target) {
    target.setField1(source.getField1());
    target.setField2(source.getField5());
    target.setField3(source.getField2());
    target.setField4(source.getField4());
    target.setField5(source.getField3());
}
```

We're looking to refactor large parts of this project and as part of it, our customer has requested that we document these mappings before we look to refactor with a better implementation.

There are several hundred of these mappings and before we get one of team to go through them all by hand, does anyone know of any tools that could analyse this code and produce a simple mapping document. All mapping have been strictly performed using getters/setters with no direct property access.

We can't give the actual code to our customer due to IP restrictions, and also it's the (non-technical) business who need this information, so ideally we need a very simple output, describing the mapping from source to target.

These transformers are still occasionally updated while we work on a new version, so I'd really prefer something that could generate the documentation we're after directly from the code rather than comments/annotations that would have to be manually updated by developers.